# Tornado - Get variable from URL

Tags: tornado

I have two handlers. In the first one (FooHandler) I show a form, in the GET method, and get the value of the field, POST method. Once obtained that value I wanna pass it to another handler through the URI. Then the BarHandler catch it and is able to make a query.

```
class FooHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.render("templates/fooForm.html")


    def post(self):
        var1 = self.get_argument('var1') #number

        self.redirect('/query/{}'.format(var1))


class BarHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, var1):
        q = Query....

def main():
    io_loop = tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance()
    connect("test", host="localhost", port=27017, io_loop=io_loop)

    app = tornado.web.Application(
    [
        (r"/", FooHandler),
        (r"/query/\d+", BarHandler)
        ], debug = True,
    )
    app.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I get this error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1443, in _execute
    result = method(*self.path_args, **self.path_kwargs)
TypeError: get() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

I'm not sure how to pass the var1 from FooHandler and catch it in BarHandler. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.URLSpec):

> Any groups in the regex will be passed in to the handler’s get/post/etc methods as arguments.

You will need to use a group in your regex path, if you want pass a part of the path to the handler.

You should define your path as:

```python
(r"/query/(\d+)", BarHandler)
```